# How to determine 2nd Normal Form in a Relation with 2 candidate keys?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a Student relation described as below:

```
Student(ID,Name,Email,GPA,PostalCode)
```

and within this relation, the functional dependencies are as such:

```
Name -> {Email,GPA, PostalCode}
ID-> {Email, GPA, PostalCode}
```

Would this relation be in 2nd Normal Form?

Comment: Your table only allows unique names?

Comment: Let's assume it allows only unique names. Would that make both name and ID candidate keys?